# "TypeError:path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not list" while creating directory

Tags: python

I made a function for create a new directory, and i pass the directory name as a parameter. Here is the function:

```
def CreateDirectory(name):
    if os.path.isdir(name):
        print("Directory already exists")
    else:
        print("Directory created")
        os.mkdir(name)
```

I need to create a few directories, so i call the function with this:

```
for i in range (len(folder)):
    CreateDirectory(folder[i])
```

I get the "folder" list from a Json file, and he looks like this

```
['TestFolder']
```

Comment: check `folder` again. looks like item in it is also a list, at least one.

Comment: print out `folder[i]` that you passed to `CreateDirectory` and check that it is indeed a string

Answer (score 0):

in your settings.py file, ensure that you do not define STATIC_ROOT or MEDIA_ROOT variable as a list.